# Какие знания требуют у стажеров-программистов java?

Tags: работа, java

Хочу попробовать устроиться стажером, сам я студент. Хотелось бы знать какие требования предъявляются к стажерам-программистам java. Вакансию в своем городе нашел, но там мало что написано.

Comment: сходи на первое попавшиеся собеседования и нам расскажешь )

Comment: проблема в том, что мне нужна эта работа) Если я приду туда, и плохо зарекомендую себя (так как не знаю что от меня будут требовать) то потеряю работу.

Comment: сходи к другим, попробуй там, загони зп - точно не возьмут тогда, а может больше предложат и возьмут )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Всё зависит от конкретной позиции и компании.

Как начинающему Java-разработчику, Вам необходимо знать следующее (как правило, по всем ниже перечисленным вопросам проводится собеседование для стажёров):

1. ООП. Инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм. Уметь объяснить и приводить примеры.
2. Java Core. Конкретно – уровни доступа, перегрузка/переопределение методов, коллекции, `exceptions`, `multithreading`.
3. SQL. Теория: реляционные базы данных, нормальные формы. Уметь написать простые запросы с использованием GROUP BY, HAVING, IN, JOIN.
4. JDBC. На основе предыдущего пункта знать, как подключаться к базе данных и выполнять SQL-запросы из Java кода.
5. С учётом того, что бОльшая часть разработок на Java – это web-приложения, то желательно ориентироваться, что такое web-сервер, web-приложение, какие инструменты есть у Java для web-разработки (Сервлеты, JSP).
6. Плюсом будет знакомство с XML, HTML, Java Script.
7. Обязательное требование сейчас – английский язык (pre-intermediate/intermediate минимум)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего будут требовать что-то со стороны j2ee (jsp, servlets, hibernate, ejb и т.д.). Либо тупо знать java-синтаксис (ну может, дадут какое-то тестовое задание), будут давать вначале несложные задачи, постепенно буду давать посложнее задания (ну этот вариант, если им реально стажер нужен на будущее, а не разработчик сразу).

Answer (score -1):

Согласен с двумя предыдущими ответами

Важнее всего знать java core (критично!):

- Базовые понятия (JRE, JDK, JVM, среда разработки)
- Основы (переменные, массивы, циклы, операторы)
- Строки
- ООП (классы, интерфейсы, 3 принципа ООП)
- Исключения
- Коллекции
- Потоки ввода\вывода
- Потоки выполнения

Важно знать или хотя бы иметь общее представление о следующем:

- java code convention (согласование об оформлении java кода)
- паттерны (шаблоны) проектирования
- sql

  Ну и желательно понимать платформу, на которой вы собираетесь работать. Если это андроид, то стоит учить android sdk, для веб разработки - jsp/servlet.

Чтобы лучше показать себя на собеседовании, стоит разобраться с теорией через практику ;). Напишите свое, хотя бы небольшое, приложение. Ну и обязательно подготовитесь по логическим задачам. Благо, в интернете их найти не сложно.

Удачи!

PS: может будет полезен [список вопросов с собеседований по java](http://ab.kh.ua/java-voprosi-s-sobesedovanij/)